# Who is the responsible for removing the Developer from the Scrum Team?

Tags: scrum, agile, self-organizing, scrum-team

I am trying to learn Scrum and I have this question:

A new Developer is having continuing conflicts with existing members of the Scrum Team, which is impacting the delivery of Increment. If necessary, who is the responsible for removing the Developer from the Scrum Team?

1. The Scrum Team is responsible
2. The Scrum Master is responsible

Which one is the correct answer?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Homework questions are generally discouraged. Try to reframe the Question to focus on a Project Management goal that's trying to be achieved.

Comment: I don't think this is in scope for project management; might be a better fit for workplace.SE.  Agree that homework questions are inappropriate - Test questions are evaluated according to the prejudice of the test creator; SE questions are evaluate based practical problems in project management.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a source of disconnect between Scrum and many real-world instances.

The Scrum answer would be that the Scrum Team is responsible. The Scrum Guide says that Scrum Teams are self-managing, which means that "they internally decide who does what, when, and how".

However, Scrum Teams often exist in the broader context of an organization. There are managers and HR departments. Removing someone from a team may be similar to having them do not work, which wouldn't be acceptable to a company that continues to provide them with compensation. The Scrum Team, perhaps with the Scrum Master, may need to raise concerns with the appropriate people and develop a plan to improve the person's ability to function on the team or to find an alternative course of action.

Answer (score 1):

"Removing an employee" is strictly a managerial / human-resources matter.

The team should not realistically expect to be able to *"vote someone off the island."*  Merely because they want to.

Comment: I know some companies that do it differently, so it is not strictly or factual. Most common, maybe..

Comment: At least in the United States, there are ***laws*** to be considered here.  The team's leaders probably need to buy their manager a cup of coffee, and sit down for a talk ... being prepared also to *listen.*

Answer (score 0):

This has to be viewed as 'Conflict Resolution'.  When new developer doesn't fit with existing members, it has to be seen with respect normal cycle of forming - storming - performing, etc.  Even after that cushion is given, if scrum master sees that there is some conflict, the best approach would be to discuss with all members including the new employee.  And Scrum master must ensure to play neutral and shares his/her feedback to respective next level.

Normally, there will be multiple scrum teams.  If one employee doesn't do well in one team, he/she may do better in other team.

In a better Performing scrum team, most of the deliverable work well because of better chemistry within the team.  If something doesn't go well, Scrum master must takes initiative step to resolve as this conflict impacts the performance of the team.  But, removing employee from the team may not be solution.  It must be discussed within the team as open & heard-out voices of the team members.